# Git: how to ignore one specific hidden folder

Tags: git

I am very new to Git. I have two hidden folders in a local repo:

```
.hidden_folder_1
.hidden_folder_2
```

I would like the `.gitignore` to only ignore `.hidden_folder_1`. How to achieve that please?

Thank you for sharing the answer. It would be great if it also works for hidden files, and for both Windows and Ubuntu.

Thank you.

Comment: add a line like this to .gitignore: `.hidden_folder_1/`

Comment: Read about [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the desired path to a file named `.gitignore` in your root directory

> It would be great if it also works for hidden files

```sh
# .gitignore
.hidden_folder_1/

# If you wish NOT to ignore path (files or folders) add the !
!.hidden_folder_1/do_not_ignore_this_file
```

---

#### How to verify if your files are ignored:

```sh
   $ git check-ignore -v *
```

---

## Tip:

Use this site to generate your base .gitignore
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To ignore hidden folders you can simply add the folder / directory name to the ***.gitignore*** file. Example :

```
.hidden_folder1
.hidden_folder2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `.hidden_folder_1` in your `.gitignore` to ignore only that particular directory.